# Looping variables using Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, openstack

I am trying to create an Ansible role which currently contains just the deployment of a security group and its associated rules. I have dozens of rules that should be added and I would like to keep it simple:

In /home/dante/roles/new/tasks/main.yml, I would like to create the security group and a loop that goes just through all ports and its associated protocol that should be added. For example, I would need something like this:

```
--- #Create the security group
- name: Create the security group
  os_security_group: 
     state: present
     name: sg_default
- name: Add the rules to the security group
    os_security_group_rule:
       security_group: sg_default
       protocol: {{protocol}} 
       port_range_min: {{port}}
       port_range_max: {{port}}
       remote_ip_prefix: 0.0.0.0/0
```

All of them are applying to the same security group. In the /home/dante/roles/new/variable folder, I should define all these ports and its associated protocol. Something like:

protocol,port: 5000,tcp; 389,udp; etc.

If is any other way to have a good separation, I am also opened to it. How can I accomplish this going through all ports & its associated ports in a loop?

**EDIT**

One step ahead:

```
- name: Add the rules to the security group
  os_security_group_rule:
       security_group: sg_default
       protocol: "{{item.protocol}}"
       port_range_min: "{{item.port}}"
       port_range_max: "{{item.port}}"
       remote_ip_prefix: 0.0.0.0/0
  loop:
      - { protocol: 'tcp', port: '22' }
      - { protocol: 'tcp', port: '8774' }
```

But I would need that inside the loop to have a file from where all these variables should be taken. In Ansible documentation, there's no example like that. Any idea how should be made?

Many thanks,
Romain

Comment: Try reading the documentation about loops: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Comment: @ceving: I have read the documentation and made a step ahead, but I would need to read the protocol&its associated port from a variables files. I have updated also my question with my progress. How can be accomplished this? Many thanks.

Comment: The role documentation explains, where to put defaults and variables: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

Comment: But in general it is not recommended to put data into roles. Put the data into `group_vars`. If it applies to all hosts, use `group_vars/all.yml`. See variable precedence: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html?highlight=group_vars#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

Comment: @ceving: I should have everything inside the role. I don't see why is not a best practice to have all variables inside of a variable folder.

Comment: A role knows how to set the security group. But if you need port 8774 or not, may differ for different hosts in different stages. But feel free to add a `vars` directory to your role in order to store the port list in the role. It is possible.

Comment: @ceving: I have found how should be done. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

In the /home/dante/roles/new/tasks/main.yml:

```
- name: Add the rules to the security group
  os_security_group_rule:
       security_group: sg_default
       protocol: "{{ item.protocol }}"
       port_range_min: "{{ item.port }}"
       port_range_max: "{{ item.port }}"
       remote_ip_prefix: 0.0.0.0/0
  with_items:
  - "{{ socket }}"
```

In the /home/dante/roles/new/variables/main.yml:

```
--- #
socket: 
- { protocol: tcp, port: 22 }
- { protocol: udp, port: 161 }
```